# My C++ Program Only Writing To The Text File The Last Entry

Tags: c++

here is the question
Write code to take full names of at least your 5 friends. You must also input species of favorite pet they
have along with the monthly budget for that pet. Save data acquired into files named (task2-1.txt)
(comma separated values for one friend per line).

the error i am facing is that it only store the last values

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size=0;
    string name, pet, budget;
    cout << "Enter The Number Of Friends : \n";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ofstream fout;
        fout << endl;
        cout << "Enter Name Of Friend " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter His Pet : ";
        cin >> pet;
        cout << "Enter His Budget : ";
        cin>>budget;
        fout.open("task2-1.txt");
        fout << name << ", " << pet << ", " << budget << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to open the file in `append` mode

Answer (score 2):

Open your file before the loop.

```
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("task2-1.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
      ...
  }
```

When you open a file for output any previous contents are lost. That is why opening the file inside the loop loses anything you previously wrote.

Comment: It Worked For Me